# How to set Condition in JavaScript event when it will onmouseover or onmousemove etc

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events

I am trying make a JavaScript condition but it is not working. 
Typically, I want to set condition if the HTML tag hover, click, inside 
if condition

`if(tag.onmouseover)` like this,

I am trying to make a slider which I serve my snippet and want to set a 
condition if the slide hover than the condition will execute.

See my snippet below:

```js
let $ = ($)=> document.querySelector($);
let _ = (_)=> document.querySelectorAll(_);
let slide = _(".slide");
let demo = $('#demo');



slide.forEach((s)=> {
 if(s.onmouseover){
   demo.innerHTML = 'true';
 } else {
   demo.innerHTML = 'false';
 }
})


// the onmouseover not working in if contidion,
```

```css
.slide_wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.slide{
    height: 80vh;
    background: cyan;
    color: brown;
    transition: 1s;
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide:hover{
    flex-grow: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide_wrapper">
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>

    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="demo" > </div>
```

Comment: That's... just not how events work. You add an event listener for a specific event type. For instance, `element.addEventListener("mouseover", function () { ... })`.

Comment: Just use mouseleave to set the innerHTML to false and mouseover to set it to true. No conditions needed.

Comment: no, I need inside if condition to work the eventHandler

Comment: Then prepare for disappointment...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I listen to mouseover and mouseout events in 3 elements in a more DRY way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59278019/how-do-i-listen-to-mouseover-and-mouseout-events-in-3-elements-in-a-more-dry-way)

Comment: Then you need to explain better what you're trying to do. The CSS `:hover` has nothing to do with the JS `onmouseover`, so at the moment you do not have any `mouseover` event that triggers, so your if/else never gets used. And if it was used, it will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use `.addEventListener()` in order to make it work as you expect. This is how it should be done:

```js
let $ = ($)=> document.querySelector($);
let _ = (_)=> document.querySelectorAll(_);
let slide = _(".slide");
let demo = $('#demo');



slide.forEach((s)=> {
  s.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    demo.innerHTML = 'true';
  });
  s.addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    demo.innerHTML = 'false';
  });
})


// the onmouseover not working in if contidion,
```

```css
.slide_wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

}
.slide{
    height: 80vh;
    background: cyan;
    color: brown;
    transition: 1s;
    margin: 5px;
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
}
.slide:hover{
    flex-grow: 5;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide_wrapper">
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>
<div class="slide"> lorem is a dummy text </div>

    </div>
    
    
    
    <div id="demo" > </div>
```

No `if`s needed because that's not how events work. Each time you move your mouse over the `.slide`, the `mouseover` event is fired on this element. And if that's a case, you want to change the `innerHTML` to `'true'`. If you leave your mouse from the element, the `mouseleave` event is fired and you want to change the text to `false`. This is how event-based communication works.